# SQL query with 2 joins

Tags: mysql, join

I am unable to join 2 separate things.

- Table 1 has user, vehicle, track (numerical values)
- Table 2 has user_num, User_Fname, User_Lname
- Table 3 has vehicle_Num, Vname
- Table 4 has track_num, tname

I have

```
SELECT c.course_name as course,  e.distance as distance, e.score as score, e.time as time, e.user as User
from hc_entries e
left join hc_course c on e.course=c.course_num
WHERE e.vehicle=$varVeh
```

The results are good but I get the numeric value of "user" and not sure how to join that value without breaking the first join.

Table information:

Table 1: hc_entries
Index,Course,vehicle,Distance,Score,Time,User
1,10,110,888,18770,1:33,1

Table 2: hc_user
User_Index, First_name, Last_name
1,Bill,Flippen

Table 3: hc_vehicle_type   (not really used in this query)
Veh_num, Veh_name
110,Jeep

Table 4: hc_course
course_num,course_name
110, mountain

When I do the above query I get the result:
mountain, 888,18770,1:33,1

I want to get:
mountain, 888,18770,1:33,Bill Flippen.

Comment: Can you format the question so we can actually read it?  I have no clue what your table layout is.

Comment: So, what output are you looking for?

Comment: Specifically, change the numbered list of tables to lead with the table names. Attaching the scripts to create these tables and perhaps insert a few rows of sample data would really help. I am gessing Table 1 is hc_entries and Table 3 is hc_course?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but it would help to see your table structure a little more clearly

```
SELECT c.course_name AS course,
       e.distance AS distance,
       e.score AS score,
       e.time AS time,
       e.user_fname AS firstname,
       e.user_lname AS lastname
  FROM hc_entries e LEFT JOIN hc_course c ON e.course = c.course_num
 WHERE e.vehicle = $varveh
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is fine, just make this slight modifiction

```
SELECT c.course_name as course,  e.distance as distance, e.score as score, e.time as time, concat(e.first_name, " ", e.last_name) as User
from hc_entries e
left join hc_course c on e.course=c.course_num
WHERE e.vehicle=$varVeh
```

Comment: Actually that won't work, the names are stored in the hc_user  table. I need to join onto the numerical entry in hc_entries-user field.